# Add an overlay timeline in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, overlay, timeline

I am new to angular.js and I am trying to add an overlay timeline view when clicking on an item.
This is an plugin I found [here](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/), but it seems to be using JQuery and I dont know how to pass the data, that I get from angular to JQuery when I click on the items. I tried some methods I found using directives, but they do not seem to be working.
What I am doing is getting the data and displaying them as follows:

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="gridListdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
      <div layout-wrap="" layout="row" class="md-padding">
        <md-card  ng-repeat="project in projects">
          <img alt="user avatar" class="md-card-image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
          <md-card-content>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>body</p>
          </md-card-content>
          <div layout="row" class="md-actions">
            <md-button ng-click="timeline(project)">Timeline</md-button >
          </div>
        </md-card>
      </div>
      <ul ng-if="checkStatus()">
    Hello
  </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Here the controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp')
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) { 
    //here we retrive the data, with the following format
      $scope.projects= [
           {
                "id": 1, 
                "start_date": "2014-03-09",
                "end_date": "2014-03-10" 
            },
            {
                "id": 2, 
                "start_date": "2014-03-10",
                "end_date": "2014-04-20" 
            }
         ];    
  });
```

And here is how I can create the timeline based on the plugin.

```
var container = document.getElementById('timeline');

  var project = [
          //this data should come from angular
            {
                "id": 1, 
                "start_date": "2014-03-09",
                "end_date": "2014-03-10" 
            },
            {
                "id": 2, 
                "start_date": "2014-03-10",
                "end_date": "2014-04-20" 
            } 
         ]




  var items = new vis.DataSet(project); 

  function customOrder (a, b) {
    // order by id
    return a.id - b.id;
  }

  var options = {
    order: customOrder,
    editable: true,
    margin: {item: 0}
  }; 
  var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
```

When the button is clicked I want to pass the data in a JQuery function.
Can anyone tell how I can do this. Thanks.

**Update 1**

I used a directive to initialize the timeline like suggested, but now when I try to pass the data into it I get the following error:

```
VM317 angular.js:12330 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: itemProvider <- item <- timelineCtrl
```

I cant figure out why this happens, here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bY8FCDO44Ws2qCeYcEaN?p=preview)!

**Update 2**

Found the error. For modal view specifying the the controller is not necessary. Removing it in the html file fixed the error.

Comment: This is far too broad. StackOverflow is not  a "how to" tutorial site. You should hve no problem finding numerous different libraries or modules for timelines. if you have integration problems ask questions then

Comment: @charlietfl You are right, I changed my question. This is main problem I have. Hope this is fine now.

Comment: Your example is not functional until you add a the Javascript parts to it as well, i.e. the controller and things. You need to create a minimal but functional example. Maybe check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You would need to initialize the timeline code in a directive so you can be assured the container element and data exists when the initialization code runs